# How do I properly display a Chinese candlestick chart using MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, github

No matter how many times I try, I have only green candles on the chart and no shadows, the data comes right as it seems to me. Can you please explain where I made a mistake?

```
Manager:
public static void getCandlestickData(String symbol, String interval, final CandlestickDataCallback callback) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String url = BASE_URL + "/v1/klines" + "?symbol=" + symbol + "&interval=" + interval;

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
                        List<CandleEntry> candleEntries = parseCandlestickData(jsonArray);
                        callback.onDataReceived(candleEntries);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        callback.onError("Error parsing JSON");
                    }
                } else {
                    callback.onError("Request failed with code: " + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                callback.onError("Request failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private static List<CandleEntry> parseCandlestickData(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
        List<CandleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray candleData = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
            long timestamp = candleData.getLong(0);
            float high = (float) candleData.getDouble(2);
            float low = (float) candleData.getDouble(3);
            float open = (float) candleData.getDouble(1);
            float close = (float) candleData.getDouble(4);
            Log.d("Candle Data", "Timestamp: " + timestamp + ", Open: " + open + ", High: " + high + ", Low: " + low + ", Close: " + close);

            if (open <= close) {
                entries.add(new CandleEntry(timestamp, high, low, open, close));
            } else {
                entries.add(new CandleEntry(timestamp, high, low, close, open));
            }
        }
        return entries;
    }

    public interface CandlestickDataCallback {
        void onDataReceived(List<CandleEntry> candleEntries);
        void onError(String message);
    }
```

Fragment:

```
private void setupChart(List<CandleEntry> entries) {
        CandleDataSet dataSet = new CandleDataSet(entries, tradingPair);
        dataSet.setDrawValues(false);

        dataSet.setDecreasingColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        dataSet.setIncreasingColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        dataSet.setShadowColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));

        candleStickChart.setData(new CandleData(dataSet));
        XAxis xAxis = candleStickChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);

        candleStickChart.invalidate();
    }
```

Увидеть подобный график у себя:
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4540d4bcd7f79a6daedba3e2212b73c45aa83249c877ad5bb30283c65f95ad4c/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f5068696c4a61792f4d50416e64726f696443686172742f6d61737465722f73637265656e73686f74732f63616e646c65737469636b63686172742e706e67